# windows server 2012 backup

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup, wbadmin, virtualization

Our backups on our virtual windows server 2012 R2 which is hosted on Hyper-V server 2012 R2 have been taking at least 3 hours longer than they used to.
We use windows Server Backup for nightly backups which backs up to a local volume. We also use a powershell script for the weekly backup which also runs through wbadmin and backs up to a network share. 
A couple weeks ago the backups started taking 3-5 hours longer.  I monitored them and noticed that they have been taking hours to compact the virtual hard disks at the end of the backups.
I refereed to the following link about this process and it should not be happening for every backup.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2524602/en-us

We installed windows updates after this problem began but its is still happening for every backup.
We have also tried configuring the backup performance for fast performance which only saved 20-30 minutes and the compacting of virtual hard disk still occurs.

What can we do to stop this?

-edit-

The nightly backup is a full system backup. The weekly backup is  of the C: and D: (data) drives.

Weekly backup Powershell script:

```
#—————————————–Start script—————————————————-

function SendEmail($To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $attachment, $smtpServer)
{
         Send-MailMessage -To $To -Subject $Subject -From $From -Body $Body -Attachment $attachment -SmtpServer $smtpServer
}
$emailto_techsupport=
$emailto_owner=
$emailfrom=
$day=(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)
$hname="NAME"
$backuplocation= "\\NAME2.DOMAIN.WKS\NAME-WEEKLY"
$backupContents= "\\NAME2.DOMAIN.WKS\NAME-WEEKLY\*"
$backuplog="$backuplocation"+(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)+"-backup-$hname.log"
$emailserver="NAME3" 


function Out-FileForce {
PARAM($backuplocation)
PROCESS
{
    if(Test-Path $backuplocation)
    {
        Out-File -inputObject $_ -append -filepath $backuplocation
    }
    else
    {
        new-item -force -path $backuplocation -value $_ -type file
    }
}
}

#Delete contents of Backup location before we do a new backup
#Remove-Item $backupContents -recurse -Confirm:$false

Write-Output ("———————– Backup started on – $(Get-Date –f o) ————————-") | Out-FileForce "$backuplog"
$Error.Clear()
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:$backuplocation "-include:d:,c:" -vsscopy -quiet | Out-FileForce "$backuplog"
if(!$?)
    {
        Write-Output ("———————– An error has occurred! Check it please!. – $(Get-Date –f o) ————————-") | Out-File "$backuplog" -Append
    SendEmail -To "$emailto_techsupport" -From "$emailfrom" -Subject "backup failed" -Body "The backup from NAME to NAME2 has failed! Please check attached log." -attachment "$backuplog" -smtpServer "$emailserver"
    break 

     }

Write-Output ("———————– Everything is OK! – $(Get-Date –f o) ————————-") | Out-File "$backuplog" -Append
SendEmail -To "$emailto_techsupport"  -From "$emailfrom" -Subject "Backup $hname OK" -Body "The NAME->NAME2 weekly backup  has succeeded!" -attachment "$backuplog" -smtpServer "$emailserver" .

#——————————————–End script——————————————————
```

Comment: Are you backing up entire volumes or only certain folders on your source volumes? Can you edit your question to include the exact `WBADMIN` command line with options that you're using?

Comment: I've added the details you requested Twisty